# WFDB SWIG Wrappers connection with Visual Studio c# project

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, wrapper, swig

i'm relatively new to the topic of wrappers and would be glad if someone could send me some tips, how could i start visual studio (C#) project which would be using wfdb library (written in C). My goal is to read and present signals from physionet database in c# app.
I've followed all the steps from:
[enter link description here](http://www.physionet.org/physiotools/wfdb-windows-quick-start.shtml)

Using win xp and VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on this project

http://wfdbcsharpwrapper.codeplex.com